# How to call Standard REST service in POST request using JSforce?

Tags: apex, rest-api, node.js, jsforce, node-salesforce

I am using JSforce, a module of Node.js for Salesforce. The login credentials are obviously not correct in this script but they are correct in original script and they are working fine. Here is app.js

> var http = require('http');
>   var express = require("express");
>   var app = express();
>   var jsforce = require('jsforce');
>   var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
>     oauth2 : {
>       // you can change loginUrl to connect to sandbox or prerelease env.
>       loginUrl : 'loginURl',
>       clientId : 'client_id',
>       clientSecret : 'secret_id_35686',
>       redirectUri : 'localhost:4000/'
>     }
>   });
>   var username = 'username';
>   var password = 'passowrd';
>   app.set('view engine', 'pug');
>   //body to be sent for post
>   var body = {
>     Auth0__Id: 'test_id',
>     us__c : 'Pending - New Hire',
>     Recope : '012F0000001E1lvIAC',
>   };
>   conn.login(username, password, function(err, userInfo) {
>     if (err) { return console.error(err); }
>     app.get('/forms', function(req, res){
>       res.render('form.pug', { check : conn.accessToken });
>     });
>      **// this is where the problem is in my opinion
>
>     var options = {
>
>     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
>
>   };
>
>     conn.apex.post(conn.instanceUrl     +"/services/data/v36.0/sobjects/SFDC_Employee__c/", body, options, function(err, res) {
>
>       if (err) { return console.error(err); }
>
>       console.log("response: ", res);
>
>       });
>
>    });** 
>   app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000);
>   app.listen(app.get('port'));

Here is the link to JSforce Post Apex Instructions https://jsforce.github.io/jsforce/doc/Apex.html#post. 
Here is the example of JSforce with Apex Rest API. 
https://jsforce.github.io/document/#apex-rest

**Is it necessary for me to include "options" parameter for defining metadata and headers? If yes! How can I do it? I think I am not defining it the right way?**. 
When I run this script I get this error.

*{ [NOT_FOUND: The requested resource does not exist] name: 'NOT_FOUND', errorCode: 'NOT_FOUND' }*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SFDC has two ways of exposing REST API

1)Custom apex Built

2)Standard REST API

You are trying to use JSForce for apex built while your endpoint is of Standard REST API .

Use the below for standard REST API to create records

```
// Single record creation
conn.sobject("SFDC_Employee__c").create({
Auth0_Id__c: 'sfnewcheckst_d',
Status__c: 'Pending - New Hire',
RecordTypeId: '012F00000lvIAC'
}, function(err, ret) {
  if (err || !ret.success) { return console.error(err, ret); }
     console.log("Created record id : " + ret.id);
   // ...
 });
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Can you specify it little bit more?
I have tried doing this: 
conn.instanceUrl +"/services/data/v36.0/sobjects/" +  body + "/".

Comment: Your object name is SFDC__c .I see only one underscore

Comment: Oh. Okay.
But in original script its two. I think that's the not problem.
Should SFDC__c should be variable and contain the body of the post request in your opinion?

Comment: Is your field names also end with __c

Comment: Also remove options and try. Does that work in REST API utility in workbench?

Comment: The original URL is this which I am using in my script.
Source URL + /services/data/v36.0/sobjects/SFDC_Employee__c/ 
Removing options doesn't make any difference. I checked it several times.
On https://jsforce.github.io/jsforce/doc/Apex.html#post, seems like its necessary for us to pass options parameters.
What do you think about this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39811/discussion-between-waseem-abbas-and-mohith-shrivastava).

Comment: Resource not found suggests the endpoint has some flaw.Try using postman or workbench to confirm url is correct.

Comment: @Mohith Shrivastava getting url no longer exist error from node js code. However when I try to hit the same url via postman it is working as expected. What may be the reason?